# Enum handling in Npgsql and EntityFramework7

Tags: c#, enums, npgsql, entity-framework-core

I have postgres database with some data in it.

I'm using Npgsql.EntityFramework7 adapter (version 3.1.0-beta8-2) to handle it.

The problem is when I try to get entity from context which has some enum inside of it.

In postgres I declare enum:

```
CREATE TYPE public.my_enum AS
 ENUM ('value1','value2','value3');
```

My model looks like:

```
[Table("my_table")]
public class Entity
{ 
        [Column("id")]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("type")]
        public MyEnum Type { get; set; }
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to get something from database via entity framework I receive this kind of error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type
>   my_enum to Int32

I've tried to register my enum in Npgsql (as it's pointed in [npgsql documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/enum.html)). With no effects.

Is there something I can do to handle 'proper' enums with this stack? (to have enum fields in database as strings/enums not as ints)

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the npgsql provider. You will likely have better luck getting a solution by filing on issue on their GitHub repository. https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql

Comment: While Npgsql supports enigma at the ADO.NET level, the Npgsql EF7 provider doesn't support them yet. Can you please open an issue at github.com/npgsql/npgsql to track this?

Comment: Done - https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/842. Thanks for fast replies.